# I don't understand a JavaScript code snippet

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Hello I'm training making some assert suits libraries, but I have a big problem understanding the javascript behavior in a code section. here the code.

```
(function(){
    var results;
    this.assert = function(value, desc){
        var li = document.createElement('li');

        // I got two CSS classes "pass" and "fail"
        li.className = value ? 'pass' : 'fail';

        var txt = document.createTextNode(desc);

        li.appendChild(txt);
        results.appendChild(li);

        if(!value){
            li.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'fail';
        }
        return li;
    }
    this.test(name, fn){
        //I have an UL element with ID "results"
        results = document.getElementById('results');

        //but i will create another UL element
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');

        /*and here my trouble, I don't understand the sense of change
        the value of "results" variable, and why the reference to "results" ul element
        still serves, could you explain me that please?*/
        results = assert(true, name).appendChild(ul);
        fn();
    }
})();
//and here my library working
window.onload = function(){
    test('first test', function(){
        assert(2 + 2 == 4, 'True assertion');
    });
}
```

My big problem is understanding how does it work the change of variable "results".

**From**

```
//I have an UL element with ID "results"
results = document.getElementById('results');
```

**To**

```
results = assert(true, name).appendChild(ul);
```

I understand ***assert*** method creates a ***li*** element, but i don't understand why the reference to the ***results*** ul element still works. please explain me that.

Comment: You can't append a UL to a UL, as a UL can only have LI element child nodes.

Comment: Do you want to append the li result that is returned from assert?

Comment: +1 for the book.. i am also reading this book..Secrets of the Javascript Ninja..

Comment: haha, and where are you? (on the book?)

Comment: right where you arrrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

results was declared inside the function as `var results` and Javascript uses <strike>block</strike> function scope so inside the <strike>block quote</strike> function where it's given a reference to the new ul that's been created inside of the function itself. You should read more on closures and execution context. This link should be of much help.

[Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)

Each time the function is called, it creates a new execution context in which it is placed, the function is executed, the variable result is declared inside as private and then the same private variable is given a new reference inside the new block scope created and ul is appended to the results variable.

When `results = assert(true, name).appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));` is called, the results variable in the `this.test()` scope is updated and since `this.assert()` is returning a `li` element, `ul` is appended to the `results(which now is document.getElementById('results'))` hence giving a new `ul` inside of the `li` created by `this.assert()`.

Comment: Um, interesting, then the key for undersand this is called closures?

Comment: closures is like the heart of Javascript, if you know how to manipulate closures correctly, then you are a true Javascript programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to append the li result that is returned from assert?

```
results = ul.appendChild(assert(true,name));
```

Answer (score 1):

The line following immediately invoked function expression (IIFE):

```
(function(){
    var results;
```

creates a variable *results* within the function's execution context. This function:

```
   this.test(name, fn){
        //I have an UL element with ID "results"
        results = document.getElementById('results');
```

has that execution context on its scope chain. The relationship remains after the outer function finishes, creating a closure.

Therefore, each time you call *test*, it is accessing the same *results* variable.

I suggest you read more about IIFEs and closures.

#### NB

You can't append a UL to a UL as they can only have LI as element child nodes. Also, assuming that *this* within the IIFE is not sensible as in strict mode it will be undefined. To fix that, pass the global object to the IIFE and use it:

```
(function (global) {
    var results;

    global.assert = function(value, desc){

 ...

}(this));
```

Comment: thanks for editing my answer..i wanted to do the same but couldn't log in.. :)